# F# recursive type: method vs function type inference differences

Tags: f#, type-inference, recursive-datastructures, recursive-type

Can someone explain please why in F# type-inference seems to work differently (or some other aspect I don't understand?) between class methods and functions.

Imagine the following (simplified):

```
type Node<'T> = Node2 of 'T * 'T
type Digit<'T> = One of 'T | Two of 'T * 'T
type Tree<'T> =
    | Empty
    | Single of 'T
    | Deep of prefix : Digit<'T> * deeper : Tree<Node<'T>>
    with
    static member Add (value : 'T) (tree : Tree<'T>) : Tree<'T> =
        match tree with
        | Empty -> Single value
        | Single a -> Deep (One value, Empty)
        | Deep (One a, deeper) -> Deep (Two (value, a), deeper)
        | Deep (Two (b, a), deeper) -> Deep (One value, deeper |> Tree.Add (Node2 (b, a)))

let rec add (value : 'T) (tree : Tree<'T>) : Tree<'T> =
    match tree with
    | Empty -> Single value
    | Single a -> Deep (One value, Empty)
    | Deep (One a, deeper) -> Deep (Two (value, a), deeper)
    | Deep (Two (b, a), deeper) -> Deep (One value, deeper |> add (Node2 (b, a)))
```

Note that static method `Add` and function `add` have identical implementation and both call itself recursively.

Yet former compiles fine but latter report an error:

```
Type mismatch. Expecting a
    Tree<Node<'T>> -> Tree<Node<'T>>    
but given a
    Tree<'T> -> Tree<'T>    
The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''T' and 'Node<'T>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the free floating function `add`, the generic type parameter belongs to the function itself (`add<'T>`).

However, in the static member function, the type parameter actually belongs to the class (`Tree<'T>`).

Why does this matter? Because when you refer to the function itself, the compiler assumes that the type parameter is unchanged unless otherwise specified. It won't guess a different one, because that could hide a huge category of type mismatch errors.

However, it doesn't make the same assumption for the *type* to which the function belongs.

If you check the parameters, the call to `add` is assumed to be a call to `add<'T>`, which causes an infinite generic recursion and doesn't compile.

**But**, the call to `Tree.Add` is inferred to be a call to `Tree<Node<'T>>.Add`, **not** to `Tree<'T>.Add`. It's a different function call altogether.

If you explicitly annotate the type:

```
static member Add (value : 'T) (tree : Tree<'T>) : Tree<'T> =
    // ...
    | Deep (Two (b, a), deeper) -> Deep (One value, deeper |> Tree<'T>.Add (Node2 (b, a)))
```

you will get the exact same type mismatch / infinite type error as on the free function.

Likewise you get the error if you make it an instance member and refer to the same instance:

```
member this.Add (value : 'T) (tree : Tree<'T>) : Tree<'T> =
    // ...
    | Deep (Two (b, a), deeper) -> Deep (One value, deeper |> this.Add (Node2 (b, a)))
```

Vice-versa, you can make the free function compile by annotating the type parameter, so that the compiler will not assume "it's the same symbol, so must refer to the same value":

```
let rec add<'T> (value : 'T) (tree : Tree<'T>) : Tree<'T> =
    // ...
    | Deep (Two (b, a), deeper) -> Deep (One value, deeper |> add (Node2 (b, a)))
```

Comment: Actually, even only adding type argument to function binding 'let rec add<'T> ...' helped.

Comment: Oh, nice. It seems the compiler only makes the same-instance assumption if the name is exactly the same. I corrected my answer.